# Can you use weights to avoid split brain in a quorum?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-computing, high-availability, quorum

We are looking at deploying a clustered db and we would like to scale the number of nodes up and down in the system with some systems having one, two or three nodes.  The Percona Clustered DB has a weighted quorum mechanism.  I think it is possible to choose the weights to break symmetry so that split brain is always avoided.  However, I cannot find any literature saying this is so which makes me doubt myself.

Here is the idea.  Assign each node one of the following weights: 127 + 0, 127 + 1, 127 + 2, 127 + 4, 127 + 8, 127 + 16, .. and so on.

Given two disjoint subsets, *a* and *b*, of nodes in the cluster the two requirements that I think have to be maintained are:

1) if a subset, *a*, has more nodes than another *b*, then the sum of its weights, *w(a)*, will always be greater than the the sum of the weights of the other set..

```
|a| > |b| --> w(a) > w(b)
```

2) Symmetry breaking.. given any two subsets then the weights won't be equal.  This is the requirement that avoids split brain with an even number of nodes.

```
|a| = |b| --> w(a) != w(b)
```

Are there any problems with this approach?  If so what are they?

More problem description...

1. Ideally we'd have the same solution for multiple node configurations to save on testing.
2. The node weights can't be changed dynamically (they can.. but it's not completely safe.. limitation of the Percona cluster and possibly the quorum algorithm?).
3. Percona will recalculate the total node weights after a clean shutdown of a node.

Comment: You are limited in the number of subsets to the size of the number used for the subsetting.  Essentially, you are assigning one bit for each node.  Whether or not that is a limitation depends on your configuration.

Comment: Yes...  But in practice the number of nodes in the cluster will not be enormous.     As the size of the clusters grows the overhead of the clusters talking to one another to keep in sync grows as well.  So the cluster size is limited in other ways (depending on how things are set up).  I could also choose a larger initial weight than 127 as well.  So the limitation in size is not a problem in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it will act as you describe, but appears unnecessarily complicated for what you describe. As far as I can tell from a web search (https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/06/12/percona-xtradb-cluster-quorum-availability-cluster/) when the system is running normally, it knows what the sum of the weights on each node are. After loss of connectivity, a connected subset will only allow writes if it still has MORE than 50% of the weights. In a potential split-brain situation, it is impossible for both sides of the split to believe that they both have MORE than 50% of the weights, because then the sum of the weights from each half would have to add up to more than the sum of all of the weights, which is impossible.

You do avoid both sides going read only if the split is exactly down the middle - but this is not what is normally meant by split brain. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-brain_(computing). If your goal is to maximize the probability of some remainder still being able to write after a failure, or to maximize the availability of writes to clients after a failure, my guess is that your best guess is to start considering what likely failures there are, given your physical network topology, and factor this into your calculation. It seems unlikely that each of the possible patterns of unavailablities are equally likely.

If you have an odd number of nodes and give each a weight of one, no split will leave an equal weight in each side, because the total weight must be odd. If you have an even number of nodes, give one node a weight of two and the others a weight of one each. Then you again have a total weight that is odd, so no split can give each half the same weight. Of course, if you lose one node in the split then the remainder can split equally as e.g. A | B,C,D| E,F,G but I'm not sure if you want E,F,G to continue in this situation, because if the split was only two-way as A,B,C,D | E,F,G you would probably want A,B,C,D to continue, and E,F,G can't tell whether the split is A | B,C,D | E,F,G or A,B,C,D | E,F,G

Comment: You certainly have a point.  However, the thing we're working on gets deployed multiple places with different topologies (probably either 1, 2 or 3 nodes but possibly 5 or 7 nodes).   I am trying to use the same architecture with one solution for all topologies to reduces the number of configurations we have to test separately.  E.g. we can start with 1 node add 2 more then have a failure to come back to 2 nodes, or a network failure and come down to three lots of one.

Comment: Percona recalculates the quorum weights when you have a node do a clean shutdown.  Which means the 3 to 2 case would happen during hot swapping.  Also changing the node weight at runtime is a little unsafe and really should be done with a restart.  So ideally I want to pick the weights at start up.  So I'm looking for the generic solution that will work for the three, two or one node (e.g the three node cluster devolves into a master-slave).

Comment: I've edited the question to add these limitations to the problem.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is your equal weights for an odd number of nodes solution will have split brain after clean shut down of one node.

Comment: For the case when you want to keep the weights for each node fixed but be able to start off with different subsets of nodes, your solution does indeed seem to have an advantage over a simpler one.